# Update without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, user-interface, refresh

I'm using this code to move items from one list to another and back and forth using POST and GET calls. However, after every change the page refreshes. I'm trying to figure out how to have the lists update and changes applied, without having the page refresh. Is this possible?

Just going through the code, I can't tell what's causing the page to refresh, but I'm guessing it has to do with the HTML button?

JS:

```
var user;


$(document).ready(function() {
  //Populate the users pick list
  var strHTMLSiteUsers = "";
  $().SPServices({
      operation: "GetUserCollectionFromSite",
      async: true,
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).find("User").each(function() {
          strHTMLSiteUsers += "<option value='" + $(this).attr("LoginName") + "'>" + $(this).attr("Name") + "</option>";
        });
        $("#my_SiteUsers").append(strHTMLSiteUsers);
      }
  });
  RefreshGroupLists();
});

function RefreshGroupLists(){
  var strHTMLAvailable = "";
  var strHTMLAssigned = "";
  var arrOptionsAssigned = new Array();
  var intOpts = 0;
  var booMatch;
  var booErr = "false";

  //current user
  user = $('#my_SiteUsers').val();

  $("#my_SPGroupsAssigned").html("");
  $("#my_SPGroupsAvailable").html("");

  if($("#my_SiteUsers").attr("value") == 0){
    alert("You must select a user");
    return;
  }

  //Populate the Groups Assigned
  $().SPServices({
      operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
      userLoginName: user,
      async: true,
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).find("errorstring").each(function() {
          if(user='default'){
            return;
          }else{
      alert("User not found");
      booErr = "true";
      return;
        }
        });
        $(xData.responseXML).find("Group").each(function() {
          strHTMLAvailable += "<option value='" + $(this).attr("Name") + "'>" + $(this).attr("Name") + "</option>";
          arrOptionsAssigned[intOpts] = $(this).attr("Name");
          intOpts = intOpts + 1;
        });
        $("#my_SPGroupsAssigned").append(strHTMLAvailable);
      }
  });

  //Populate available site groups
  if(booErr == "false"){
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromSite",
        async: true,
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
          $(xData.responseXML).find("Group").each(function() {
            booMatch = "false";
            for (var i=0;i<=arrOptionsAssigned.length;i++){
              if($(this).attr("Name") == arrOptionsAssigned[i]){
                booMatch = "true";
                break;
              }
            }
            if(booMatch == "false"){
              strHTMLAssigned += "<option value='" + $(this).attr("Name") + "'>" + $(this).attr("Name") + "</option>";
            }
          });
          $("#my_SPGroupsAvailable").append(strHTMLAssigned);
        }
    });
  }
}

function AddGroupsToUser(){
  var i;

  if($("#my_SiteUsers").attr("value") == 0){
    alert("You must select a user");
    return;
  }

  if($("#my_SPGroupsAvailable").val() == null){
    alert("You haven't selected any groups to add");
    return;
  }
  else{
    var arrGroups = $("#my_SPGroupsAvailable").val();

    for (i=0;i<arrGroups.length;i++){
      $().SPServices({
          operation: "AddUserToGroup",
          groupName: arrGroups[i],
          userLoginName: user,
          async: true,
          completefunc: null
      });
    }
    RefreshGroupLists();
  }
}

function RemoveGroupsFromUser(){
  var i

  if($("#my_SiteUsers").attr("value") == 0){
    alert("You must select a user");
    return;
  }

  if($("#my_SPGroupsAssigned").val() == null){
    alert("You haven't selected any groups to remove");
    return;
  }
  else{
    var arrGroups = $("#my_SPGroupsAssigned").val();

    for (i=0;i<arrGroups.length;i++){
      $().SPServices({
          operation: "RemoveUserFromGroup",
          groupName: arrGroups[i],
          userLoginName: user,
          async: true,
          completefunc: null
      });
    }
    RefreshGroupLists();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center">
      <font style="font-weight:bold">Select a User:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
      <select id="my_SiteUsers" style="width:250px;" onchange="RefreshGroupLists()">
        <option value='default' disabled="disabled">Select a user</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class='ms-vh2'>Available Groups</th>
    <th></th>
    <th class='ms-vh2'>Assigned Groups</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='ms-vb2'>
      <select id="my_SPGroupsAvailable" style="width:150px;height:150px;" multiple="multiple"></select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="my_AddGroupsToUser" style="width:40px;" onclick="AddGroupsToUser()">&gt;&gt;</button><br><br>
      <button id="my_RemoveGroupsFromUser" style="width:40px;" onclick="RemoveGroupsFromUser()">&lt;&lt;</button></td>
    <td class='ms-vb2'>
      <select id="my_SPGroupsAssigned" style="width:150px;height:150px;" multiple="multiple"></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

**EDIT: I realize the Button was causing the Refresh, so I added this to the JS. Now the page doesn't refresh but the lists don't update correctly. So if I select 5 groups and move them, maybe 1 or 2 will move "visually", then when I refresh they all moved. So it's just some UI issues right now. 
`.click(function() { return false; });`**

Comment: use $.ajax() to send a POST or a GET

Comment: In your real HTML is there a form surrounding that table?

Comment: I think the functions I'm using are using ajax. They're an option to set it to true or false. I've set it to true.

Comment: @nahime the table is wrapped around the body tag. Nothing else is around it. I updated OP though. Perhaps I should make a new question?

Comment: @Batman see if I've understood the problem and my answer solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AddGroupsToUser function add a returnfunc that will call RefreshGroupList. Then remove the call at RefreshGroupList just after the for cycle.

Your posted code will run a cycle and start n async operations. After the cycle it will update the list, but since the operations are async some of them have finished and some are running. That's why you see the list partially updated.

This should update the list at every "save" of a group:

```
function AddGroupsToUser(){
  var i;

  if($("#my_SiteUsers").attr("value") == 0){
    alert("You must select a user");
    return;
  }

  if($("#my_SPGroupsAvailable").val() == null){
    alert("You haven't selected any groups to add");
    return;
  }
  else{
    var arrGroups = $("#my_SPGroupsAvailable").val();

    for (i=0;i<arrGroups.length;i++){
      $().SPServices({
          operation: "AddUserToGroup",
          groupName: arrGroups[i],
          userLoginName: user,
          async: true,
          completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            RefreshGroupLists();
          }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, now the lists update together and the page does not refresh. Makes the entire process look much better. I was wondering if you know how I could had an animation above my table to show that it's working or progressing?